# Wordpress custom post type - permalink issue

Tags: wordpress

I am having the following problem. I have created a custom post type called services. When I create a new service, lets call it xpto, the permalink looks something like this `domain/services/xpto`. And I would like the permalink to be something like this `domain/xpto`.

My Settings->Permalinks are set to Post name `domain/sample-post`, and in the function I used to create the post in functions.php, I have tried several options in the `rewrite` argument, but to no success.

Help please.

Comment: Is there any attribute in the custom post type definition which sets the post slug? I think you can just leave that blank and it won't show up when you create the post.

Comment: Yes, there is, it's rewrite (boolean or array). I have set it to false. No luck. And when I pass an array like `'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/'),`, the permalink shown is correct, i can see `domain/xpto`, but when I navigate to that URL I get the 404, not found